# access 2010 getting max row in excel 2010

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I have a problem in accessing excel 2010 via MS access 2010.
From access 2010, I want to get max row from my excel data.
Here is my code:

```
Dim Xl As Excel.Application

Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook

Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Integer

MySheetPath = "C:\Users\myaccount\Desktop\LRLV\mydata.xlsx"

Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

Set XlBook = GetObject(MySheetPath)

Xl.Visible = True

XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(1)

With XlSheet

    lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

End With
```

When I have no excel opened, everything is okay. But when I have 1 or more excel which has been opened the variabel "lastRow" always give me "Type mismatch" error. Now I need to know how to fix it. Thank you so much before.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your problem is the unqualified reference to A1. also I'm not sure why you use GetObject when you already have an application reference

```
Dim Xl As Excel.Application

Dim XlBook As Excel.Workbook

Dim XlSheet As Excel.Worksheet

Dim lastRow As Long, i As Integer

MySheetPath = "C:\Users\myaccount\Desktop\LRLV\mydata.xlsx"

Set Xl = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Xl.Visible = True
Set XlBook = XL.Workbooks.Open(MySheetPath)

XlBook.Windows(1).Visible = True

Set XlSheet = XlBook.Worksheets(1)

With XlSheet

    lastRow = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=.Range("A1"), SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

End With
```

Answer (score 0):

`.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)` is not returning a valid range in this instance. This meas the find is unsuccessful. That is why you are getting a type mismatch.

To solve, do this:

```
Dim rng As Excel.Range

Set rng = .Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=[A1], SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    lastRow = rng.Row
Else
    'ToDo - handle the error here
EndIf
```